# React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency in reactjs useEffect

Tags: reactjs

```
const [data, setData] = useState(undefined);
useEffect(() => {
    if (changeRequests.data) {
        setData(setDefaultState(changeRequests.data));
    }
}, [changeRequests.data, setData,setDefaultState ]);

const setDefaultState = data => {
    let names = getNameList(data);
    setSelectedItems(names);
}
```

The 'setDefaultState' function makes the dependencies of useEffect Hook (at line 78) change on every render. Move it inside the useEffect callback. Alternatively, wrap the 'setDefaultState' definition into its own useCallback() Hook

```
const [resultsFallback] = useState([]);
const getNameList = res => {
let jList = getJData(res);
let jNames = resultsFallback;
jNames = jList.map(j => {
    return `${j.joggers}`
});
return jNames;
```

}

**The 'getNameList' function makes the dependencies of useCallback Hook change on every render. To fix this, wrap the 'getNameList' definition into its own useCallback() Hook**

Comment: you can include the `setDefaultState` in the list of dependencies which will make the warning go away

Comment: If setDefaultState isn't used elsewhere you can move it into the useEffect function or do it how Barry suggested

Answer (score 1):

Change your `setDefaultState` declaration to this:

```
const setDefaultState = useCallback((data) => {
  let names = getNameList(data);
  setSelectedItems(names);
}, [getNameList, setSelectedNames])
```

Don't forget to `import React, { ..., useCallback } from 'react'`

**The 'getNameList' function makes the dependencies of useCallback Hook change on every render. To fix this, wrap the 'getNameList' definition into its own useCallback() Hook**

Answer (score 0):

For error 1):The linter is telling you that you're depending on external values that may change,You can tell React to skip applying an effect if certain values haven’t changed between re-renders.If your array does not change the value, it will remain the same.
2)data should be used inside the component, here you are passing it as a argument, data should be inside the JSX expression and after re rendering it will change the value.